# Angular SCSS Global Variable Import

Tags: css, angular, sass

I would like to move over to SCSS in my Angular project. So far the only use I want from SCSS is the variables. At the moment I have been using CSS variables which work very nicely because you declare them in `:root` in my styles.css and then you can use them in all the components' CSS files in the app.

My question is whether this is possible with SCSS (a global import)? Because I find it very tedious to move from a language that imported globally by it self (CSS) to something that now requires me to import variables wherever I need it (SCSS).

I am a bit disappointed on why a better version of something would require me to do this. Therefore I am sure there must be some way to not have to import my variables in every SCSS I need them in.

For example, I want to create variables in my styles.scss, and then I want to be able to use those variables in any of my components' styles, without importing anything. In CSS variables like `--MyVar` in `:root` is accessible from any components' CSS.

Comment: Not fully sure I understand but Sass has global variables, you just need to append `!global` to your variable. Sass will compile to CSS, so I assure you anything that is possible in CSS is also possible in Sass.

Comment: By global I mean across multiple .css files. `!global` is only a statement that applies to the current .scss file it is in. If I understand it wrong, please add an official answer with an example if you don't mind :)

Comment: @PaulKruger have any of the answers solve your problem  ?

Comment: Yes sorry. This was such a long time ago! Thank you for your answer!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You don't need to import variables everytime consider this example

*theme.scss*

```
$primary-color:#00b289;
$secondary-color:#505050;

@import "components/_checkbox";
@import "components/_button";
```

as you can see I only decalre my variables once and I can use the variables inside my partial sass file.

another way is to create a partial sass file include all your variables and imported once

*theme.scss*

```
@import "_variables.scss";
@import "components/_checkbox";
@import "components/_button";
```

Answer (score 5):

I don't think u need to import scss variable everywhere wherever you want to use it

Suppose you have a file

*_variables.scss*

```
$white:#fff;
$black:#000;
```

then in `main.scss` u can import this file

*main.scss*

```
@import "variables.scss";
```

Now suppose u want to use these variables in, for eg `_button.scss` file

*_button.scss*

```
button{
 color:$black
}
```

You can directly use these variables provide that you import the `_button.scss` file in  `main.scss` file **after** `variable.scss`

Placing it after `varibles.scss` files will ensure that the variables will be accessible in `button.scss` file

*main.scss*

```
@import "variables.scss";
@import "button.scss";
```

As for CSS variables, you are free to use them SCSS,

try running the follwing snippet in [Sassmeister](https://www.sassmeister.com/)

```
:root{
  --gridWidth: 45px; 
  --gridHeight: 45px; 
}

.Grid {
    width: var(--gridWidth);
    height: var(--gridHeight);
    border: 1px solid black;
}
```

Comment: This works but you are still writing the import line. I guess whether you write an import line in main.scss or in any other component.scss it is still writing one line. So I am not sure if you are winning much here.