# Globally import scss variables, to be usable on all angular components

Tags: css, angular, typescript, sass

I have an internal library that has the colour variables, Im able to grab it from the *node_modules* and import it on any component basically, I have imported it in the styles.scss in hopes that the child components would inherit the variable making easy to use the colours.

the challenge that I'm facing is that I need to import the variables on every component before using them even though I have them imported on the styles.scss. I would like to be able to use the colors on any component basically have them imported globally and use all over the project

I have looked into this, ([Angular SCSS Global Variable Import](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51834482/angular-scss-global-variable-import))  similar question, but seems for every use you need to import which is what I don't wanna do

the ([Global scss variables for Angular components without importing them everytime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55131372/global-scss-variables-for-angular-components-without-importing-them-everytime)) first answer seem intriguing and I would like to use it in that sense, but my variables are like those of the second answer, please help

Answer (score 1):

After a thorough google search and hair pulling, finally realised the only way to achieve what I'm looking for is to add my variables to the `:root` pseudo. this way I was able to import the variable once on my main styles and just use them throughout on any component level